# How to launch an iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I know launch an application may via touch ico on the desktop. And is it start by its plistfile? Is there any other way to launch app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your own custom URL scheme:

[Guide](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

It's located in the .plist file (if the application has it)

Answer (score 6):

Register a "protocol" for your application and the iPhone OS will automatically execute your application when a link with that protocol is clicked. For instance all links with "http://" (http protocol) at the start of the link will execute the Safari browser. Links starting with "fb://" will start the Facebook application etc.

Comment: @new-soul This means that if you want to launch an application other than your own you will need to find out if it has a protocol handler.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API to launch arbitrary applications. You can launch applications that have registered for a custom URL scheme like explained in another answer.